# Daily tasks/Anything fun & challenging to automate with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework

I'm currently studying test automation with Selenium and Java. It's very fun, but I have only done basic stuff.

I've been thinking about something fun that I can do with selenium, for instance, automate daily tasks that I do. The problem is that I cannot think of anything so I would like to get your ideas on some hobby selenium projects that I can do?

Comment: I Love that you're looking to expand your knowledge of Selenium and automated testing in general. Unfortunately, this isn't really an answerable question... i mean, what is the "correct" answer going to be?

Answer (score 2):

You can try automating your daily manual tasks which you have to repeat manually every day like:

1. Filling Timesheet in your project tracker, feed your test with a CSV file or excel sheet.
2. Changing status of the issues/tasks/defects over the tracker
3. Creating new bugs/defects over the tracker (you can create selenium projects which will pick up your bugs found during manual testing and will create the same over your tracker like JIRA, TFS web explorer, HP-ALM etc.). This is what I have done (not with selenium but with Test Studio during its learning phase. We have to import test cases and defects from Client HP and one more tracker to local JIRA on daily basis for tracking purpose. So, we created a test script in Test Studio for this complete activity.
4. Use Selenium with JMeter for the purpose of performance testing (if you are interested in performance and load testing)

This is what you can do to enhance your Selenium skills and ease your day-to-day tasks.

Comment: I would love the fourth point. Any tutorial regarding this?

Comment: Definitely refer to these posts, you will need Selenium plugin for JMeter, mentioned in post itself.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211732/how-to-integrate-jmeter-with-selenium-webdriver-for-load-testing   https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler

Comment: Thanks. Any more examples? Anything FUN to automate on my spare time?

Answer (score 0):

When I was learning Selenium, I would try automating the most basic scenarios in a web page like filling out login forms, and then going ahead with whatever I want to do. That gave me plenty of new things to learn.

Also, I found [this](http://www.guru99.com/live-selenium-project.html) to be very helpful, as it gives plenty of information and a brief know how of what you can expect in real life.

Comment: Thanks. Any more examples? Anything FUN to automate on my spare time?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of things you can do using selenium , Some examples are given below :

1 - Fill your daily timesheet and mail it

2 - Save data to excel/txt file from any website

3 - Import data to any form from excel

4 - Check broken links for any webpage

5 - Get all links from web page

6 - Do functional test using selenium

7 - Bug Tracking tool management

8 - Get Reports with particular filter. For ex: Download Google analytic report daily.

And A Lot more you can do with Selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate updating CV in job portals and try automating sending mails by taking data from excel sheet